# combine selected lines/rows within a csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I need to combine lines (`$GPGGA` and `$GPVTG`) within a csv file with python and have a problem. The csv file looks like this:

```
~11:16:04.831,$GPGGA,091606.00,5149.28020915,N,01140.54074205,E
~11:16:04.861,$GPVTG,40.8,T,,,000.05,N,000.09,K,D*75
~11:16:05.833,$GPGGA,091607.00,5149.28020818,N,01140.54074319,E
~11:16:05.863,$GPVTG,40.8,T,,,000.01,N,000.01,K,D*79
```

I tried with

```
eingabe = sys.argv[1]
with open(eingabe, "rb") as file:   
    datareader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in datareader:
        if "$GPGGA" in row:
            col1 = row[0], row[1], row[3], row[5]
        if "$GPVTG" in row:
            col2 = row[0], row[1], row[2]
        print col1 + col2
```

The result is only the final line, but I need all of them

('~11:16:08.827', '$GPGGA', '5149.28021200', '01140.54075064', '~11:16:08.867', '$GPVTG', '40.8')

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say combine? Can you give a clear sample input, and then your expected output; the output you are describing doesn't match any input lines of the sample you posted; so its difficult to know what you want in the end.

Comment: Can you please re-check your code for valid indentations. For instance `if "$GPGGA" in row` has supposedly one indentation too much and print one too little.

Comment: The indentations of your `if` statement and `print` statement should be modified.

Comment: Combine means write selected lines into a new line based on the expressions $GPGGA and $GPVTG. As you see in the csv input it starts with $GPGGA followed by a $GPVTG line. The output now matches the current code and I also checked indentation.

Comment: The indentation is btw. still broken, but anyhow: it is still unclear what you mean with "combine"… Also notice that `file` is a built-in function in python, don't use it as variable name.

Comment: Sorry, if I am unclear. With combine I mean merge/join line 1 and 2 to a new line, then line 3 and 4 etc based on the expression $GPGGA and $GPVTG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> with open('1.csv') as file:
...     reader = csv.reader(file)
...     col1s = []; col2s = []
...     for row in reader:
...             if "$GPGGA" in row:
...                     col1s.append((row[0], row[1], row[2], row[5]))
...             elif "$GPVTG" in row:
...                     col2s.append((row[0], row[1], row[2]))
...     for each in zip(col1s, col2s):
...             print each[0] + each[1]
... 
('~11:16:04.831', '$GPGGA', '091606.00', '01140.54074205', '~11:16:04.861', '$GPVTG', '40.8')
('~11:16:05.833', '$GPGGA', '091607.00', '01140.54074319', '~11:16:05.863', '$GPVTG', '40.8')
>>>
```